# Best way to store the first and second word of a text file into two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char, fopen, scanf

I'm making a code for a program.
It would have three text files: 
-list1.txt having a column of words like:

```
Cat 
Dog
Fish 
Computers
```

-change.txt having two columns of text like

```
Dog  Marbles
Computers Store
```

-list2.txt being empty

The program would take list.txt, and store its words in the list2.txt, only if a word would be the first column word in change, it would store the word from the second column. 
That way, when the program would compile, the list2.txt would look like this:

```
Cat 
Marbles
Fish 
Store
```

The way I thought of doing this was to make two char arrays, one for the first column word, and the second for....well, the second one. Then mane a nice if and write the second value if true.
The problem is I can't figure a good way to store those words in the arrays correctly.

Here's my code for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    ///////////OPENING THE TEXT FILES
FILE *sp ;
sp= fopen("list.txt", "r");
if(sp==NULL){
printf("can't open list");
exit(1);
}

FILE *change;
change = fopen("change.txt", "r");
if(change==NULL){
printf("can't open change");
exit(1);
}

FILE *sp2;
sp2 = fopen("list.txt", "w");
if(sp2==NULL){
printf("can't open list2");
exit(1);
}

char word[100]; 
char key[20]; //the char array for the element TO replace
char mod[20]; //the char array for the element TO BE replaced

while(fscanf(sp, "%s", word)==1){
    fprintf(sp2, "%s\n", word);} //the copy machine

fclose(sp);
fclose(sp2);
return 0;
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you format the code properly and add a language tag to attract more people who can help you?

Comment: Are you perhaps worried that some words may get too long to be stored into the array?

Comment: It's a revision for an exam in 2 weeks.

Comment: Banana, no. The length can be eaisly adjusted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses an array to store up to 10 lines, 2 words of up to 19 characters. Change the 10 in `#define LINE 10` to a larger number to handle more lines. For more than a few hundred lines, consider dynamically allocating memory for the change.txt word pairs.
After the word pairs have been read from the change.txt file, the list1.txt file is read word by word. Each word is compared to the the first word of the change word pairs. If a match is found, the index of of the match is stored and used to print the second word of the pair to the list2.txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE 10
#define WORDLEN 20

int main()
{
    //array for list of words up to LINE lines, two words of up to WORDLEN characters
    char acChange[LINE][2][WORDLEN] = {{{0}}};
    char word[WORDLEN] = {0};
    int line = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int match = 0;
    FILE *list1 = NULL;
    FILE *list2 = NULL;
    FILE *change = NULL;

    if ( ( change = fopen ( "change.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open change.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf ( change, "%19s", word)) == 1) {//read the pairs of words
        strcpy ( acChange[line][each], word);
        each++;
        if ( each == 2) {//got second word, advance to next line
            each = 0;
            line++;
        }
        if ( line >= LINE) {//do not go beyond array dimension
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose ( change);

    if ( ( list1 = fopen ( "list1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {//open list1 for reading
        printf ( "could not open list1.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ( ( list2 = fopen ( "list2.txt", "w")) == NULL) {//open list2 for writing
        printf ( "could not create list2.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf ( list1, "%19s", word)) == 1) {//read a word
        match = -1;
        for ( each = 0; each < line; each++) {
            if ( strcmp ( acChange[each][0], word) == 0) {// is it in the change array
                match = each;//save the index
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( match == -1) {
            fprintf ( list2, "%s\n", word);//not in the change array
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( list2, "%s\n", acChange[match][1]);//write the second word to the file
        }
    }

    fclose ( list1);
    fclose ( list2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
The program works great, and I can understand why.
The only small problem for me is the syntax of "char acChange[LINE][2][WORDLEN] = {{{0}}};"
I mean this is the array of the change words, but this is the first time I've met with a 3d array

Answer (score 0):

Try turning it into a comma delimitted (trim whitespace) line instead of columns, and store it into array one.

When you want to check if there is a change, create another array with the new values and compare lengths using a for loop for both arrays.

if the lengths are different, for the elements you compare you have a change. If you want to add another condition besides checking the length you can include extra conditions depending on how deep you want to filter your strings.

I don't know what language you're using but there are libraries to make this a much easier task. For example c# has an exclude method to check for differences in a list that you would fill from a comma delimitted text file.

I'm not sure if this helps, but if you can be a bit more specific maybe I can help a bit more.

```
pseudo code
-open the text file and split every single word between each comma using a while
loop.
-store that in a 1d Array
-use that 1d array for the length you want to loop through
-store it into another array like this 
- (declare array 1)
  (declare array 2)


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        {
                           newarray[i] == array[i]; 
                        }
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        {
                          if (newarray[i].length < 1 )
                            { 
                    write down new values into your text file using
this new array

 }
```

I don't know c syntax this is javascript so it should be fairly similar. I gave you some logic to get you going

Comment: I forgot to add, when you find the difference depending on what position you want it to be in, check out the push - pop methods in an array. That will either bring your element to the front or back of the array

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is regular C, Sorry, forgot to mention. I was wondering of including a string, and then storing the text from change.txt into a 1d array of them. Then make a for loop going every second element (so the one with the key). Tho I'm not sure how to write down the comparison algorythm code (for the IF) to determine.